# Blogger: Author name is not showing on PopularPosts

Tags: blogger

I can't seem to discover why both `<data:post.author/>` and `<data:post.dateHeader/>` tags won't show inside the PopularPosts widget... 

This is what I have inside the `<b:includable id='main'>` in my PopularPosts widget:

```
<ul>
    <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>    
        <li>
            Posted by: <data:post.author/>
            <data:post.dateHeader/> 
            <a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a>
        </li>
     </b:loop>
 </ul>
```

When I inspect the blog web page it says: `<!--Can't find substitution for tag [post.author]-->`

The `<data:post.title/>` shows just fine, while the others don't... Could someone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<data:post.author/>` and `<data:post.dateHeader/>` aren't available in popular posts of layout version 2.

You can upgrade your template to version 3 and use the following new tags:

```
<data:post.author.name/>
<data:post.date/>
```

**To upgrade Blogger template:**

Replace the `<html>` attribute `b:version='1'` with `b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' b:templateVersion='1.3.0'`

Comment: How to upgrade my template? I googled it but I don't think I did it the right way... even using the tags you mentioned, they aren't showing. Thanks for answering

Comment: I did it! Thanks for the help